# Рандом выдает одно и тоже

Tags: python

```
ask = int(input("Введите количество чисел: "))
for d in range(1):
    rand = randint(1,100)
    rand = str(rand) + " "
    result = rand * ask
    print(result)
```

и у меня в итоге выходит `12 12 12`, `14 14 14` и т.д.
мне нужно вообще что бы оно было примерно так `12 + 44 + 52`

Comment: пройдись по каждой строчке и посмотри что она делает. Ну например, что такое ``ask``? А сколько итераций делает цикл ``range(1)``? Что именно происходит в ``rand * ask``?

Comment: ' + '.join(str(random.randint(1,100)) for _ in range(int(input("Введите количество чисел: "))))

Comment: А за что тут минусы-то?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так:

```py
from random import randint

ask = int(input("Введите количество чисел: "))

result = ""

for d in range(ask):
    rand = randint(1,100)
    rand = str(rand) + " "
    result += rand

print(result)
```

И если +:

```py
from random import randint

ask = int(input("Введите количество чисел: "))

result = ""

for d in range(ask - 1):
    rand = randint(1,100)
    rand = str(rand) + " + "
    result += rand

result += str(randint(1,100))

print(result)
```

Comment: хахах кто ж быстрее))

Comment: причём абсолютно одинаковый код))

Comment: Я первый, `ответ дан 2 минуты назад` и `ответ дан 51 секунду назад`!

Comment: эх, не успел)))

Comment: репутацию не даёте))))
ахах

Comment: но плюсик поставил

Comment: @PeterKolosov а у вас мой...

Comment: Ну тогда не `rand = str(rand) + " "`, а `rand = str(rand) + " + "`

Comment: взаимно, спасибо!!)

Comment: я хочу изменить "пробел" на "+"
    rand = str(rand) + " "
и в принте выходит то что в конце тоже есть плюс, как его убрать?

Comment: вот так: `result = result[:-3]`

Comment: @nchistov В таких случаях, если разрыв репутации между отвечающими большой, то принято отдавать приоритет ответа новичкам, чтобы у них рос рейтинг. Но у вас рейтинг в общем не сильно разный, поэтому тут уж кто чуть раньше - того и тапки )

Comment: спасибо, жаль обоим не могу поставить галочку(

Comment: @CrazyElf ахах)

Comment: @GrafixWay не за что)) поставьте этому человеку)

Comment: @GrafixWay просто надо немного подождать.

Comment: @PeterKolosov спасибо, редко получается отвечать! ❤

Comment: спасибо всем, я просто вообще не давно на пайтоне начал писать, а то все время на библиотеках писал

Comment: Обоим по голосу отдал за спортивное поведение)

Comment: кто...поставил...минусы?

Answer (score 5):

У вас неправильная реализация. Нужно сделать так:

```py
from random import randint

ask = int(input("Введите количество чисел: "))
result = ""

for d in range(ask):
    rand = randint(1,100)
    rand = str(rand) + " + "
    result += rand # прибавляем случайное число к строке result

result = result[:-3]

print(result)
```

Comment: а что делает :-3?

Comment: обрезает строку

Comment: чтобы не было лишних плюсов

Comment: а почему именно -3?

Comment: Потому что в этом случае, исходная строка будет, например, `23 + 54 + 12 + `, ненужный остаток " + " имеет длину 3, и вот поэтому `-3`

Comment: @PeterKolosov это костыль. По-нормальному нужно через join делать.

Comment: кто...поставил...минусы?

Answer (score 5):

```
import random

k = int(input())

arr = random.choices(range(1, 101), k=k)
print(" + ".join(map(str, arr)))
```